# Filtering Only 1 Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap menu with a search field but am running into a problem where it filters EVERY dropdown menu. For example, if I go to search from the dropdown with the search field, then choose another field, it will remove other dropdown items. In other word I only want to filter the single dropdown. Here is my code with an example of the problem:

```js
// Search
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function() {
  var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(".dropdown-item").each(function() {
    var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    $(this).closest('.dropdown-item')[s.indexOf(g) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  });
});
```

```css
#search-criteria {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

span.searchitem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-sm btn-light" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <input class="form-control" id="search-criteria" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header">Heading 1</h6>
    <a class="dropdown-item"><span class="searchitem">heading 1</span>li 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item"><span class="searchitem">heading 1</span>li 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item"><span class="searchitem">heading 1</span>li 3</a>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-sm btn-light" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Edit</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <a href="#" id="someid" class="dropdown-item">Toggle Circle Crop</a>
      <a href="#" id="someid" class="dropdown-item">Toggle Oval Crop</a>
      <a href="#" id="someid" class="dropdown-item">Bring to Front</a>
      <a href="#" id="someid" class="dropdown-item">Bring Forward</a>
      <a href="#" id="someid" class="dropdown-item">Send Backwards</a>
      <a href="#" id="someid" class="dropdown-item">Send to Back</a>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"#search-criteria"` function select its `.parent` to get the dropdown items...

```
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function() {
  var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown-item").each(function() {
    var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    $(this)[s.indexOf(g) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  });
});
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/imYoVQu2TM

Comment: Thanks. This looks close but why is it not now seeing matching (for example, if you type 3, even the item with 3 is hidden) terms at: https://www.codeply.com/go/imYoVQu2TM

Comment: The search logic was wrong, I updated the answer and Codeply